# How to change js path in manifest.js - Lazy loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have webpack configured and it was working fine until I applied lazy load.
Path to js folder is `public/js` where all my js files stored.
It was working fine for vendor files as I am specifying direct path in the `index.html`.
This fails in the case of lazy loading, because manifest file uses dynamic path which by default takes public/*files*.js.

Following are the temporary solutions

1. Move all lazy loading files to `public/` (*need to change the folder structure.*)
2. Edit the `manifest.js` as follows

   ```
   ... e){return i.p+""+({}[e]||e)+".js"}( ...
   ```

   to

   ```
   ... e){return "js/"+i.p+""+({}[e]||e)+".js"}( ...
   ```

   (*need to edit manifest after build*)

Is there any option to handle this from **webpack**?